# Tensorflow2 Unknown device in Tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

I cannot display the device placement in tensorboard graph. The only device is "unknown device" (see screenshot below).

In the python script, I activated the following option:

```
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
```

And indeed, the log device placement information is logged correctly in the python output:

```
Executing op Fill in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
Executing op VarIsInitializedOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
...
```

The tracing is activated as follows:

```
tf.summary.trace_on(graph=True, profiler=True)
```

And the graph is displayed correctly in tensorboard but the device name is simply wrong:
[image]

OS: Windows 10 x64
Python: 3.8
Tensorflow: 2.2.0
GPU

Comment: Same with Tenosrflow 2.6, Linux, Windows